# how to replace single backslash with empty character in string?

Tags: android, string, replace, backslash

I want to replace single backslash with empty character from string.
when i use syntax :- message =  message.replaceAll("\","");  then it gives me error when i use  message =  message.replaceAll("\"",""); this syntax then it does not have any effect

Comment: Try using message.replaceAll("\\","");

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Back Slash itself is an escape Character,so you need to use double backslash to achieve it,as in

```
message=message.replaceAll("\\","");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use  `message.replaceAll("\\","");` instead

Answer (score 1):

It should be either:

```
message = message.replaceAll("\\\\","");
```

Or

```
message = message.replace("\\","");
```